# How instruct javapackager for headless debian package

Tags: java, deb

I would like to use the javapackager to create
a .DEB package for a headless java application.
The java application doesn't need an icon. Can I
instruct the javapackager to deal with a
headless java application. Currently I get this error:

```
xdg-desktop-menu: No writable system menu directory found.
```

The error is already an improvement since I
installed xdg-utils. But now I prefer that the
package does not try anything with xdg. Is this
possible to produce a .DEB package for a headless

Java application with the javapackager?

**Edit 03.12.2020:**
It seems that the default configuration of the javapackager expects xdg-utils. For a headless debian package would prefer that the installer creates a link in /usr/bin maybe?

Comment: To clarify, are you using `javapackager` or `jpackage` (the former was removed in Java 11, I think, and the latter is a replacement added in Java 14)?

Comment: I am using javapackager from JDK 1.8.